# change text format of an span dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex, text

I need to change field dynamic and set format with this code i a formatting my zip code its text come from server end like

```
123456789
```

and this jQuery method change this value format
    1234-56789

```
var ZIptext = $("#ZipLabel").text();
    var reformat = ZIptext.replace(/(\d{5})/g, function (match) {
        return match + "-";
    });
    $("#ZipLabel").text(reformat.replace(/\-$/, ""))
```

but know i am facing problem i need to change format of my fax number

```
3453454354
```

and it should be like

```
345-345-4354
```

So can someone help me

Comment: `'3453454354'.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/,'$1-$2-$3')`

Comment: use input mask if you are willing to use plugin. use [digitalbush](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with capturing group regex

```js
var res = '3453454354'.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');

document.write(res);
```

Comment: your ans solved my issue 
but one more thing if this is need on c# side

Comment: @Coder : I'm not familiar with it.... please look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Coder glad to help :)

Comment: can we restrict a user to enter only twwo digit afther decimal and only one decimal allowded

Comment: @Coder : in html5 you can use `pattern` attribute with required regex

Comment: in simple html with jquarry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111759/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-coder).

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to this one [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352499/add-dash-in-auto-complete-phone-number)

You can do this using:

```
'345345345'.replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4})/,'$1-$2-$3'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to do it generically.

The first argument is the input string, the second is the separator character, and the third is an array of lengths to separate the input with. You can specify a `'*'` as the last argument as well.

```
function separate(_input, _separator, _lengths) {
  var output = [], i = 0;
  for(i=0; i<_lengths.length; i++) {
    if(_input.length <= _lengths[i] || _lengths[i] === '*') {
      output.push(_input);
      break;
    }
    output.push(_input.substr(0, _lengths[i]));
    _input = _input.substr(_lengths[i]);
  }
  return output.join(_separator);
}
```

Usage examples:

```
separate('3453454354', '-', [3, 3, 4]); // returns "345-345-4354"

separate('3453454354', '-', [4,'*']); // returns "3453-454354"
```