# phone number rails js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, phone-number, masking

Is is possible to do this in rails. I have read about turbolinks. and have tried to adapt it for rails but was unable.

```js
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="(555) 555-5555"/>
```

this code comes from: [Mask US phone number string with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651207/mask-us-phone-number-string-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can include the javascript code inside the Rails App, If you are gonna use this field in all over the application you can use this script in application.js
in the folder app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
```

Include this in application.js

If you have page specific javascripts you can create a separate js file and include that in folder app/assets/javascripts

Comment: I put it in the app/assets/javascripts folder and then it should work. I am using a form_for. I have copied the html. I will need to change the id from  'phone' to 'venue_phone' and change 'input' to 'textarea'.  `<div class="field"> <div class="form-text">Phone</div>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="1.5" name="venue[phone]" id="venue_phone">
</textarea>
  </div>`