# Masking a phone number with javascript, deleting characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to mask a phone number with javascript in this format `+4 (444) 444-44-88`

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29335409/5206428) I came up with this solution

```
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  let x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{1})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,2})/);
  e.target.value ='+' + x[1] + '(' + x[2] + ')' + x[3] + '-' + x[4] + '-' + x[5];
});
```

It works but the problem is that it seems like I can't delete characters from input.
As soon as I hit `'-'`  backspace doesn't work. But, for example, if I delete every number `x[i]` then all the strings `'-'` and `'()'` can be deleted.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0arjm04/2/)

Comment: @binariedMe do you mean change input type for phone input  to 'password'?

Comment: @binariedMe It just changes number to *. What I want is when a person enters numbers they are shown in this format +4 (444) 444-44-88

Comment: apologies, I didn't understand the question correctly. I'd remove the comment.

Comment: I have added a working solution. Can you please try @Allan

Answer (score 0):

The reason why backspace is not working is that when you hit backspace, it actually deletes "-" but then your event listener again reassign the value to input box and it looks as if backspace is not working at all.

Here is a messy but working solution to your problem :

```
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  let hasUnclosedParanthesis = !e.target.value.match(/\)/g) && e.target.value.match(/\(/g);
  //alert(e.target.value, hasUnclosedParanthesis);
  let x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{1})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,2})/);
  let pn = '+';
  if(x[1]) {
  pn += x[1];
  }
  if(x[2] && !hasUnclosedParanthesis) {
  pn += '(' + x[2] + ')';
  }
  if(x[2] && hasUnclosedParanthesis) {
  pn += '(' + x[2].substring(0, x[2].length-1) + ')';
  }
  if(x[3]) {
  pn += x[3];
  }
  if(x[4]) {
  pn += '-' + x[4];
  }
  if(x[5]) {
  pn += x[5];
  }
  e.target.value = pn;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement that.

Comment: In original answer I think it works based on conditional expression `e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '')`

Comment: Yes, you can write the same if conditions with ternary operators... both will do the same. This just was required because you had this opening/closing bracket... that needed special condition