# Format phone number string from google form to spreadsheets into an email draft using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, numbers, format

For the most part of this code I have down. The only issue I am having is formatting a phone number that has been inputted to the Google Form. On the Spreadsheet the values come in looking like 1234567890, just a string of numbers. I am using `body.replaceText("%PHONE1%", row[2]);` to replace %PHONE1% in the template document. Issue is it numbers come in the same as the spreadsheet 1234567890 and I want the phone number to look like (123) 456-7890.
It may possibly something like

Utilities.formatString('%11.6f', 123.456);

Please help, im a super newb at any type of scripting any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I just realized that Utilities.formatString is completely wrong. But there may be another option to add script to the form so that as they input the phone number it automatically formats...

Comment: Good answer with regexes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651207/mask-us-phone-number-string-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
function formatPhoneNumber()
{
  var s='1234567890';
  if(s)
  {
    var mA=s.match(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);
    var s=Utilities.formatString('(%s) %s-%s', mA[1],mA[2],mA[3]);
    var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Phone Number')
  }
}
```