Javascript Phone Number mask for azerbaijani numbers
I've been trying to implement a code snippet for the telephone input field in my WordPress FunnelKit builder checkout, but it isn't working as expected when users re-enter their numbers. I aim to create an input format similar to the one on this example, with a few modifications. Specifically, I would like to fix the initial 0 digit at the start of the field, so as the user types, the format appears as:
(056) 234-56-67
The 0 digit should remain fixed at the start as they continue typing. Below is the previous code snippet I added to functions.php, but it doesn’t fully achieve the intended behavior. Could you please assist with a solution that aligns with this format?
Thank you!
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'funnelkit_phone_mask' );

function funnelkit_phone_mask() {
   wc_enqueue_js( "
      $('#tel_no, #alt_tel_no')
      .keydown(function(e) {
         var key = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
         var phone = $(this);
         // Don't allow anything but numbers and some control keys
         if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
           if (phone.val().length === 0) {
            phone.val('(' + phone.val()); // add opening bracket
           }
           if (phone.val().length === 4) {
            phone.val(phone.val() + ') '); // add closing bracket and space after area code
           }
           if (phone.val().length === 9) {
            phone.val(phone.val() + '-'); // add first hyphen after 3 digits
           }
           if (phone.val().length === 12) {
            phone.val(phone.val() + '-'); // add second hyphen after 2 more digits
           }
         }
         return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
        });
   " );
}

// Function to set the placeholder and maxlength for both phone fields
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'funnelkit_phone_placeholder' );

function funnelkit_phone_placeholder() {
   wc_enqueue_js( "
      // Set placeholder and maxlength for tel_no field
      $('#tel_no').attr('placeholder', 'Tel. nömrəsi (___) ___-__-__');
      $('#tel_no').attr('maxlength', '15'); // Limit input to 15 characters

      // Set placeholder for alt_tel_no field
      $('#alt_tel_no').attr('placeholder', 'Alternativ tel. nomresi (___) ___-__-__');
      $('#alt_tel_no').attr('maxlength', '15'); // Limit input to 15 characters
   " );
}


There are some nice scripts here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651207/mask-us-phone-number-string-with-javascript

Something like this may help;


  var code;

  window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  };
  
  document.getElementById('organization_phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    if(code !== 8){
    var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,2})/);
    e.target.value = '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + '-' + x[3] + '-' + x[4];
  }});
 <input type="text" id="organization_phone" name="organization_phone"  required placeholder="(056) 234-56-67" value="0">
 



